# Cannot get site loaded with Apache on Mac

Tags: macos, apache, web, osx-elcapitan

I'm running El Capitan and trying to get my website hosted locally for development with Apache (that came with the OS). I followed the instructions [here](http://osxdaily.com/2012/09/02/start-apache-web-server-mac-os-x/) exactly. I made an `anthony.conf` file and put the Directory text in there, I replaced the actual directory with `/Users/anthony/dev/web/unfinished-asteroids/` and then placed my web files in there. I started apache and navigated for localhost/~anthony but I get the

> Not Found: The requested URL /~anthony was not found on this server.

standard 404 error. When I navigate to localhost it works fine and I get the "It works" from the index.html that is located in `/Library/WebServer/Documents`, I even changed that index.html file and it works fine.

Any ideas why I'm not able to see my website using apache? All I did was download [this github repository](https://github.com/rezoner/unfinished-asteroids) and place it in my unfinished-asteroids folder, the index.html is at the root.

Comment: It needs to be in ~/Sites else you will need to modify the userdir directives   That point ~username to ~sites as well.

Comment: Where is the ~/Sites directory?

Comment: Ok, so I made a "Sites" folder in the anthony User folder. I also changed the directory text in the anthony.conf file to say "/Users/anthony/Sites/", I placed a simple index.html file at the root of the Sites folder, but it still doesn't work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it looks like there are a couple of extra steps that you need to do.  There isn't really anything too special about apache that comes with OSX, so your standard apache configurations will work.  but to get Userdir (~username) working on El Capitan,this is what I had to do

Edit `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`

on (or near) line 166,  uncomment

`loadModule userdir_module libexec/apache2/mod_userdir.so`

then on line 493 uncomment

`Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf`

then edit file `/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf`

uncomment line 16

`Include /private/etc/apache2/users/*.conf`

then in `/etc/apache2/users/anthony.conf`

```
<Directory "/Users/anthony/Sites/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

then `sudo apachectl restart`

That should make `http://localhost/~anthony` point to your sites directory.

Logs are stored in `/var/log/apache2`

Now if all you want is web access to say your dev directory you can do something like this..  (don't make any of the changes listed above)

in `/etc/apache2/other/`  create a file called `mydev.conf` (name doesn't really matter, save it needs to end in .conf')

and put this in that file

```
Alias /dev /Users/anthony/dev/

 <Directory "/Users/anthony/dev">
   Options Indexes MultiViews
   Require all granted
 </Directory>
```

and reload apache (`sudo apachectl restart`)

then you will be able to access your dev folder at `http://localhost/dev` and should be able to access your page at `http://localhost/dev/web/unfinished-asteroids/`

you can adjust the paths at will above, just need to make sure that the user or group `_www` has access to it, and that paths in the alias and the directory match.

Comment: Awesome. This worked. Thank you so much! So are those modules loaded by default in the versions of Apache on previous OSX versions? Or is this just something weird about El Capitan?